# How to do the validation for checkbox in php

Tags: php

How to do the validation for checkbox on server side php. I wrote an input tag with name type and value very common tags for html. 
I wrote some code in php after google but didn't work. Any help appreciated.
html code

```
....
<input tags of name>
<input tags of category with select and options tag>
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-check pl-3 pt-1">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input name="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Check Box">
                <a href="#">Option 1</a>
                </label>
            </div>
```

php code like:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];


    $name_error = "";
    $checkbox_error = "";

    if (!isset($checkbox)){
        $checkbox_error = true;
        echo "<span class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Please select checkbox</span>";
    } if { 
$name error define here...
} else {
```

Comment: you need to provide some more details this doesn't explains the problem.

Comment: Where does the `$toscheckbox` variable come from?

Comment: What is `$toscheckbox` assigned to?

Comment: add your html field

Comment: i don't show any input and a span can be a checkbox in front design but he can't be a real input for the POST or a GET sending form.

Comment: Okay just give me a sec ..I edit my question now

Comment: Please edit the question to show where `$toscheckbox=` is set up. Also show the HTML you are sending to this page.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question.. just edit now

Comment: Should we assume that `<div class="row">` means there will be more? So, not just ONE checkbox, but possibly multiple?

Comment: yes i just saw this typo mistake when edit the code

Comment: Oh, and .... $checkbox will always be set ;) You should do `if (!isset($_POST['checkbox'])){}` instead.

Comment: it's an amazing coincidence, I guess, I just came accross another question with exactly the same (peculiar) $toscheckbox variable...

Comment: @Randall no it was a bootstrap class for aligning the boxes in a row. That was my understanding i dont know what is the actual meaning of this row meaning.

Comment: *"I wrote some code in php after google but didn't work."* - @rayvic Did you get any errors by any chance, in using PHP's error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php set to catch and display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isset`, checkboxes that are not checked don't get submitted to the server

```
if(!isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
    //do something when not set

}
```

What you have now will give you an undefined offset warning/error because you could be assigning a value from an index in the `$_POST` array that does not exist.  So you have to check it before assigning it.

```
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; //throws warning.

if(isset($checkbox)){

}
```

If you are just looking to set a value for it you can use a trinary operator

```
$checkbox = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : false;
```

This is equivalent to doing this

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']);
}else{
    $checkbox = false;
}
```

Now checkbox will equal `$_POST['checkbox']` if it's set, and `false` if it's  not. Then you can check it with a simple boolean comparison.

```
if( $checkbox ){ ... }
```

New in PHP7 is the `NULL coalesce` operator so with PHP7 you can do this

```
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'] ?? false;
```

Although I haven't tried that, still waiting on the CSO to upgrade our server from PHP 5.6

Comment: The extra examples and explanation is very helpful to explain the subtleties of why it works and wouldn't work. Good answer.

Comment: @Randall - thanks, I try to explain things because I am mainly self taught so I know how confusing things can be when you don't have a well rounded foundation to build on.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix
I tried with undefined offset warning 
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; 
if(isset($checkbox)){
}

It works but when i set this value by checked the box it still shows the warning ..

Comment: Actually i am just a newbie if i found any errors or stuck some where i just google it ..